# Android Studio showing that SDK is already installed but it isn't

Tags: android-studio

I've been using Android Studio for a long time and this time I have to install it to a work computer which has strict internet access.

When it tries to install the SDK automatically it gives me this (see picture below) but the folder does not even exist.

[image]

Additionally when going into settings and trying to check for updates I get the following error: `Connection failed (Read timed out). Please check network connection and try again.`
I tried setting HTTP Proxy to `No proxy` and also tried other proxy settings but that seems to have no effect.

How am i supposed to proceed?

Comment: make sure update url's are not restricted in network. you might need to check with your network admin.

Comment: @KaranMer where can I find the update URL?

Comment: it is inside sdk manager, but check if you can open  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml this is the repository url

Comment: I am able to open that with the browser.

Comment: pls indicate if this solved the problem...

Comment: I added a bug report to the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227481272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. I had to change my HTTP Proxy to office proxy and it started working.

By adding manual proxy config and logging in there.

Comment: what config can i use ?

Comment: So for me I just disabled the Company VPN and it worked. Did someone report this to Google?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the Offline work option in the **Settings** - **Gradle**
2. Under File Menu, click on **Invalidate Caches / Restart**
3. Test your network source (Wi-fi/cable), if it works fine

Now, try again..

Comment: Sorry I can't access office computer outside office hours. But the "Offline work" was never enabled and I can't start a new project or open one because I do not have the Android Sdk and I can't download one via Android Studio because it says that I already have it installed in a folder that does not exist. Thus I can't go under the File Menu

Comment: Every time I start up the Android Studio it tells me that "No Android SDK found", before continuing, you must download the necessary components or select an existing SDK. So I click next and on next tab it should download SDK for me, but it says that it is already installed.

Comment: Well.. the issue was quite simple, I just had to change the HTTP Proxy to office proxy and it started working..

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my laptop's default language to English because I had a different language set as the default, so I couldn't download the Android SDK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).